# Create QR Code in PDF file

Tags: magento2, pdf

I want to create a QRCode (contains a simply string) in a new PDF file.

I use Endroid/QrCode which use BaconQrCode. However, I need to specify version and this is put in hard in the code. I don't know how to override this code. I post a question about that but, visibly, it's off of topic...

Here, you can see there are several version : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

So now, I have a new question :

How to create a QrCode in Magento 2? What do I need to use?
I only want to encode (not decode)

Comment: what do you mean by "I need to specify version". please provide more information. to you want to generate a QR-code from a simple URL? in which PDF do you want to add the QR-code.

Comment: I updated my post. I only want to generate qrcode from a simply label in a PDF I created from scratch